# I can't write json file with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just want to save an array in a json file. But I don't know what's going on. In dataUser.json there is only "{}"

```
//test.cs
void Start() { Test(); }
void Test()
{
    string[,] dataUser = new string[,] 
    {
        {"NgocPhat", "03"},
        {"PhatNgoc", "02"}
    };
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(dataUser, true);
    File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/dataUser.json", json);    
}
```

Output

```
//dataJson.json
{}

//https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRDHJ.png
```

Comment: I don't think you're using ToJson correctly. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html

Comment: `string[,]` is a 2-dimensional array (not a jagged-array), but JSON (and JavaScript) don't support 2-dimensional arrays. Anyway, it looks like what you really want is to serialize a `Dictionary<String,String>` to JSON, not `string[,]`.

Comment: @VictorWilson ?? What do you mean? That's pretty much how you would use it .. if your data structure was supported by the Unity Serializer of course

Comment: @derHugo not sure how one would get the Unity Serializer to support a jagged array of strings, since it has no public properties of value here.  The documentation makes it pretty clear the intended use case is for POCOs etc. "...therefore the object you pass in must be supported by the serializer: it must be a MonoBehaviour, ScriptableObject, or plain class/struct with the Serializable attribute applied."

Comment: @VictorWilson Well as said your data structure needs to be supported (clearly not the case here) .. but stating `I don't think you're using ToJson correctly.` is not really helpful then I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

As per the Unity documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html), the following excerpt describes your issue:

> Internally, this method uses the Unity serializer; therefore the
> object you pass in must be supported by the serializer: it must be a
> MonoBehaviour, ScriptableObject, or plain class/struct with the
> Serializable attribute applied.

What that tells us, in a subtle way, is that certain .Net recognisable objects aren't recognised by the Unity serialiser. This can be seen in the Unity Inspector, for eample, if you tried to add a `string[,]` field to a MonoBehaviour, you wouldn’t see it in the Inspector.

Note, you can't serialise a `string[,]` or a `Dictionary<Tk, Tv>` either, no matter how you decorate them. A rule of thumb, if you can't see it in the Inspector, you won't be able to serialise it.

The Unity JsonUtility serialsier is also a little more restrictive. You can't (de)serialise single objects. It will only (de)serialise a class or struct.

With that said, it looks like you're in charge of the JSON format, so with that in mind, you might want to do something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class DataUser
{
    public string name;
    public string code;
}

[Serializable]
public class DataUsers
{
    public DataUser [ ] users;
}
```

```
void Test()
{
    var dataUsersClass = new DataUsers
    {
        users = new DataUser[]
        {
            new DataUser { name = "NgocPhat", code = "03"},
            new DataUser { name = "PhatNgoc", code = "02"}
        }
    };
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(dataUser, true);
    File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/dataUser.json", json);    
}
```

The result should then look like:

```json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "NgocPhat",
            "code": "03"
        },
        {
            "name": "PhatNgoc",
            "code": "02"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation linked from someone's comment probably points to the problem:

> "Internally, this method uses the Unity serializer; therefore the
> object you pass in must be supported by the serializer: it must be a
> MonoBehaviour, ScriptableObject, or plain class/struct with the
> Serializable attribute applied."

My guess is that the base array class doesn't have that attribute? I think that a property of type array could be serialized, but maybe not the way you're doing it.

I'm guessing the solution will be to make a dummy class to serialize like this:

```
public class Dummy
{
    [Serializable]
    public string[,] Data { get; set; }
}

string[,] dataUser = new string[,] 
{
    {"NgocPhat", "03"},
    {"PhatNgoc", "02"}
};
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(new Dummy { Data = dataUser }, true);
```

FYI, that will nest the array inside the Data property in the JSON.

You could also try something like Newtonsoft.JSON which might be a little more forgiving with your original code.

Comment: Even with that attribute the Unity Serializer does not serialize any complex collections like jagged or multidimensional arrays or dictionaries etc only plain array and list. See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this exactly answers your question. But i have been using json de & / serializing for a while and it works fine with this method!

So first you want to save / write stuff to a json file. (A list in this case)

```
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
                serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"YOURPATH"))
                using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, loaned); //loaned is the name of the list.
                }
```

Put this in a function Save() and then just call it or whatever method // way you want to do it.

Then if you want to read the informatino in the json file, // load the data.

```
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
                serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;


                using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"YOURPATH"))
                {
                    loaned = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Bok>>(File.ReadAllText(@"YOURPATH"));
                    serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    loaned = (List<Bok>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(List<Bok>)); //loaned = the list, and then the type list, and the class/object "Bok"
                }
```

Disclaimer : Im not an expert and im sure there are more effect methods but this one works just fine!